# V8 Segfault when using Global with Value

Tags: c++, v8, embedded-v8

I am getting started with embedding v8 and I am encountering some 'unexpected behavior'. The following code produces a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when the variable `value_` is not `Reset` at the end (see comment in code). However, the same does not apply for the context `context_`. Why? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22698594/10829442) seems to be related but does not provide an explanation.

My expectation was that `isolate->Dispose()` takes care of both.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "include/libplatform/libplatform.h"
#include "include/v8.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  {
    // Initialize V8.
    // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();

    v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
    v8::Global<v8::Context> context_;
    v8::Global<v8::String> value_;
    {
      // Global Context Setup
      v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
      v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

      v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);

      v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate, NULL, global);
      context_.Reset(isolate, context);

      // Global Value Setup
      v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);
      v8::Local<v8::String> value = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "segfault", v8::NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
      value_.Reset(isolate, value);
    }

    // value_.Reset(); // <- Why is this line needed?
    // context_.Reset(); // <- Why is this line NOT needed?
    isolate->Dispose();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  }

  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
  return 0;
}
```

**Build setup:**

Follow the instruction in *Run the example* from the official [Getting started with embedding V8](https://v8.dev/docs/embed#run-the-example). Save the code to *sample/wasm.cc* and execute following commands:

```
$ g++ -I. -O2 -Iinclude samples/segfault.cc -o segfault  -lv8_monolith -Lout.gn/x64.release.sample/obj/ -pthread -std=c++17
$ ./segfault
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `v8::Global` has a [destructor](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/7.0/include/v8.h#L910) that will call `Reset()`.
- The global handles are held in the `Isolate`, after `Isolate::Dispose()`, [the global handles will be freed](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/lkgr/7.0/src/isolate.cc#L2758).

Thus, if you don't call `Global::Reset()`, but `Dispose` the `Isolate` before the destruction of a `Global`, the destructor of `Global` will cause a access-after-free, which is a typical Undefined Behavior.

`Reset()` will set the internal pointer to `nullptr`, and subsequent call will check this fact and doesn't do anything. That's why you can add a `Reset()` before `Dispose()` to avoid the UB.

That's also true for your `Global<Context>`, it doesn't demonstrate itself because access-after-free doesn't always trigger a segfault.

Comment: Is there a reason, why `Global::Reset()` is not automatically called on all registered global objects when `Isolate::Dispose()` is invoked?

Comment: @mhk `Global` essentially contains a pointer to the storage node. `Isolate` has no way to change that pointer value. Because `Isolate` doesn't know where the `Global` is in user's code.